# Data is not rendering properly angular

Tags: angular, webpack, uglifyjs

I have an application which was working fine before, but I accidentally updated global npm version and it started creating mess. I install latest node version, it doesn't work. Started giving

```
ERROR in main-24a640c16d91945b788f.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc ()) [./~/image-map-creator/dist/image-map-creator.bundle.js:1,222][main-24a640c16d91945b788f.js:172081,185]
```

I solve it by install uglifyjs web plugin and adding it to webpack. It work but now the UI is messed like this
[image: UI is not displaying properly]

I have checked the network request and data is there but the UI is not rendering accordingly

[image: Network request showing data]

How can i solve this.

Comment: Share the code for better resolution

Comment: @Arjun what code you are asking for ? it was working before npm update ... now it is not ... so i think it is nothing to do with code

Comment: Have you tried using nvm to install the version of node you need and re-installing the dependencies?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor already tried not working

Comment: Then it has to be a code issue.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor yeah it was ... i was calling a function and turns it was return undefined or null and the ui was crashing

Comment: Glad you got it figured out